Apollo query getting "403 Forbidden" with Github graphql api
with Angular 18x, I am trying to get github grapql response using apollo in the front end. getting error as 403 Forbidden
Here is my graphql provider:[graphql.provider.ts]:
import { ApplicationConfig, inject } from "@angular/core";
import { ApolloClientOptions, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client/core";
import { Apollo, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from "apollo-angular";
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-angular/http";

export const githubData = {
  token: "ghp_M4T0mL4l44BHWyD6dGmQLk3Fovcb",
  username: "train",
};

//const uri = "https://countries.trevorblades.com/graphql"; // <-- add the URL of the GraphQL server here
const uri = "https://api.github.com/graphql"; // <-- add the URL of the GraphQL server here

const headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Authentication: "bearer " + githubData["token"],
};

export function apolloOptionsFactory(): ApolloClientOptions<any> {
  const httpLink = inject(HttpLink);
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({ uri }),
    headers: headers,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}

export const graphqlProvider: ApplicationConfig["providers"] = [
  Apollo,
  {
    provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
    useFactory: apolloOptionsFactory,
  },
];

here is the query:
const GET_REPOS = gql`
  query {
    user(login: "kentcdodds") {
      repositories(first: 100) {
        totalCount
        nodes {
          name
        }
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
          hasNextPage
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
export { GET_REPOS };

in the service I am calling to get data:
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Apollo } from "apollo-angular";
import { GET_REPOS } from "../graphql/graphql.queries";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class GitServiceService {
  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

  getGitData() {
    this.apollo
      .query({
        query: GET_REPOS,
      })
      .subscribe(({ data, error }) => {
        console.log("data", data);
      });
  }
}

but getting error in networks as:
Request URL:https://api.github.com/graphql
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:20.207.73.85:443
Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin

what I am missing here? I'm using angular 18.x
I updated the "link" property in apolloOptionsFactory function as follows:
link: httpLink.create({ uri, withCredentials: true }),
after this update, I am getting CORS issue.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.github.com/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

